# Any reason why RabbitMQ doesn't create exchange on start application?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I have strange RabbitMQ behavior (as for me of course).

When I started spring boot web application, in my configuration I'm trying to create rabbit direct exchange:

```
@Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(directExchangeName);
    }
```

But when app started, I can't find this exchanger in RabbitMQ management. But it’s interesting, because in ApplicationContext I can see this bean.

This exchanger start to show in RabbitMQ management after first call to it.

Is I'm missing something? Or can it be issue with my configuration?

Comment: Also I'm tried to configure all topics and bindings with RabbitAdmin. In this way all works well, I see all queues and exchangers. But I don't wont to use RabbitAdmin, I want to declare all beans easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` to auto-declare exchanges, queues, bindings.

And, even then, the declarations will not occur until some component (listener container, template) opens a connection; the admin registers as a connection listener.

Comment: Is any way to do this without RabbitAdmin? I'm tried do the same in pet project. In spring boot rabbit documentation all beans created without RabbitAdmin, and it's work.

Comment: Spring Boot automatically configures a `RabbitAdmin` bean; that's why it works there. You can do it manually by using the AMQP API directly (get a connection from the connection factory, then get a channel from the connection, then `queueDeclare()` then close the channel, connection. But it's a lot easier to just add an admin bean.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Maybe it's my fault, but when I'm started app, I didn't find RabbitAdmin bean in AppContext. I'm use spring boot.

Comment: I am completely sure; I am the project lead for spring-amqp.

Comment: *"You need a RabbitAdmin @Bean to auto-declare exchanges, queues, bindings."* Can you elaborate?

Comment: See the documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/broker-configuration.html . When using Spring Biot, it will automatically configure the admin bean.